# Spacing in headline between number and text

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script

How do I change the spacing between the number and the title of a section? I would like to have the following:

> **1.**(1cm space)**Section name**

Answer (score 9):

This adjusts the space for all section headings, and also for sub(sub)sections to 1cm:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{1cm}}
\makeatother
```

You can modify this redefinition as you desire. It works with KOMA-Script classes as well, as I notice your [koma-script](/questions/tagged/koma-script) tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to make \hspace{1cm} start at the beginning of the line rather than after the section number?

Comment: @Sebastian: I also have Sebastian's question - did you find a solution?

Comment: Ha, found the solution. You will find that using `\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\hbox to 1cm{\csname the#1\endcsname}}` will do the trick.

Comment: @Christoph Use `\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thesection\autodot \hfil}}`.

Answer (score 6):

The "**1.**", "(1cm space)" and "**Section name**" are each components of the sectional command and, the [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) provides commands for manipulating this, [and much more](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf). Specifically, `titlesec` provides

```
\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
```

to change the format of a sectional title. You could use the latter in the following way:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}% Http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
...
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\sffamily\large}{\thesection.}{\hspace{1cm}}{}%
```

which typesets `\section` in `\bfseries` (**bold**), `\sffamily` (sans serif) and `\large`, with a period `.` after the section number `\thesection`, followed by a `1cm` gap and then the title. This is what it looks like if you only modify the `\section` format as given above:

[image: Titlesec formatting of \section]

Comment: Using `titlesec` with a KOMA-Script class (see the [tag:koma-script] tag of the question) is not longer recommended.

Answer (score 1):

With a KOMA-Script class you can redefine the KOMA-Script command `\sectionformat`:

```
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thesection\autodot\hspace{1cm}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thesection\autodot\hspace{1cm}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Note that this suggestion needs at least KOMA-Script version 3.17. Current version is 3.23.

---

Because of the comments to Stephans answer: If there should be a static width of eg. `1cm` for the section number including the space, then

```
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thesection\autodot\hfil}}
```

can be used.

Comment: And if number and space should have static width (see the comment to Johannes' answer), e.g., again `\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thesection\autodot\hfil}}` can be used.