# Reduce the space between the number and the text of headlines in KOMA-Script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

Similar to [Spacing in headline between number and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25989) i want to reduce the space between the number and the text of headlines.

However, since i use the `scrreprt` class, the `titlesec` package is not an option. Can anybody help? I want it for all chapters, sections and subsections...

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Too much space between the number and this text here}
I like to have a single space instead   
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{Wombat}}%
}`

Comment: this causes an "indent" of the chapter heading

Comment: \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\noindent
       \mbox{\noindent
        \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot      \IfUsePrefixLine{~}{}}
  }   would do what i want but doesn't seem a nice solution

Comment: That cannot do what you want. But nevertheless, you need to have some patience and wait for esdd, or schweinebacke, or somebody else with an up to date system and some KOMA knowledge.

Comment: If you know how that you won't use a prefix, a simple `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\mbox{\thechapter\autodot~}} ` should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space after the chapter number is part of `\chapterformat`. The default definition is:

```
\newcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}
```

The space here is set by `\enskip` only if the chapter heading is printed without prefix line. `\enskip` is similar to `\hspace{.5em}`. So to reduce the space into a word space you can change `\enskip`, e.g., in `\nobreakspace`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\nobreakspace}}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Too much space between the number and this text here}
I like to have a single space instead   
\end{document}
```

Note, the `%` in the definition are important!