# Set the space between the subsubsection title and its number

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I would like to decrease the space between the subsubsection title and its number only. Space between chapters\sections\subsections name and their number should not be changed. I have tried to follow the solution provided here 
[Spacing in headline between number and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25989/spacing-in-headline-between-number-and-text) but my file complied with errors. 
I'm using the following template:
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/cambridge-university-engineering-department-(cued)-latex-phd-thesis-template.

The template can be also found here 
https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/releases/tag/v2.4

Comment: Is the template ONLY available on sharelates?

Comment: It is also available here http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/

Comment: I'm going to update my question by adding the new link of the template.

Comment: Okay, it gets the \subsubsection (etc.) definitions from book class.  `\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}`

Comment: The number is formatted by `\@seccntformat` which automatically adds a `\quad` to the end.  You could temporarily redefine `\@seccntformat` or `\quad`, or just add some negative space in front of the title (which is currently ignored by \subsubsection).

Comment: The titlesec version uses \titlelabel instead of \@seccntformat, but it too is used by \section, \subsection, etc.